# Firebase: Firebase app named '[DEFAULT]' already exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a website that is hosted on Firebase - you can check it out [here](https://columbia-ride-share.firebaseapp.com) if you are curious. I am running this application on a browser, currently checking it against Chrome and Safari.

In my app, I have a button that triggers a redirection to google sign in when clicked. However, as of now, I get a Page Not Found result. I wrote my app.js based off of [Firebase's instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin). Currently I get an error, "unexpected tooken: . " for "function.googleSignin(){ ". Moreover, it gives me this error:

[image]My app j.s. looks like this:

```
(function() {



 // Initialize Firebase
        const config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyAIY9XOb5QVDTxJKxtvSZRiyqgpGasHF3M",
            authDomain: "columbia-ride-share.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://columbia-ride-share.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "columbia-ride-share.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "1058399238109"
         };
         firebase.initializeApp(config);

    }()

);

function.googleSignin(){
   var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
}).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  var email = error.email;
  var credential = error.credential;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on the environment you are running this from? Is this running from a browser? what type? Are you hosting this page? How?